# What is the difference between the Windows and Linux loopback interface?

Tags: linux, windows, loopback-address

I have a WCF service on a Windows 2008 server, that listens on `127.0.0.1:19000`, that I am able to connect to externally (i.e. a pc in the same network can ping :9000, and the WCF service will 'hear' the request).

I think in linux that I would have to bind a service to the `0.0.0.0:port` address if I wanted to listen externally, and that a `127.0.0.1` address would not be able to listen externally.

Is the above correct? What is the Windows equivalent of the `0.0.0.0` address?

Looking at WireShark, it seems that Linux and Windows implement the loopback interface differently? Why is this and what are those differences?

(Or, if the question doesn't make sense, please tell me why!!)

Comment: Ordinarily, Windows distinguishes between `0.0.0.0` and `127.0.0.1` in the same way Linux does.  Have you checked with `netstat -a -n` to see what addresses are bound from the networking stack's perspective?  It is possible that WCF isn't doing what you think it is, I believe there's a kernel-mode cache that might be interfering.  It is also possible that the behaviour changes on servers with the Routing and Remote Access component configured, I'm not sure.

Comment: In My WCF configuration, the service have a base address of `<add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9000"/>`. Is localhost over TCP treated differently to HTTP?

Comment: No idea; I've never used WCF.  If you are able to establish to your satisfaction that it is WCF (rather than the TCP/IP stack) that is behaving unexpectedly you might want to post another question, appropriately tagged.  (Googling "WCF baseaddress localhost" led to a bunch of results that *suggest* to me that WCF interprets localhost as a request to listen on 0.0.0.0 rather than on 127.0.0.1, but I couldn't find anything that said so outright.)

Comment: (I did discover that if your service is hosted in IIS, it is the IIS configuration rather than the WCF configuration that determines the base address; is your WCF service self-hosted?)

Comment: Yes, the service is self hosted.